# What is the shortest description of a universal computational structure that includes a meta-circular evaluator?

Tags: it.information-theory, kolmogorov-complexity, universal-computation

I am wondering whether there is a minimal (or the shortest known) way of specifying a universal computational structure that includes a specification of a meta-circular evaluator within that structure. What are theoretical hurdles we might encounter? Is there something along these lines in the literature?

Update to elaborate a bit what I have in mind: A 1D-cellular automaton implementing the rule 110 has a very short description, but this structure is not immediately homoiconic, in fact it would require *a lot* of bits to make it homoiconic. Similarily, it takes quite a lot of states to implement a Turing machine in a Turing machine, but perhaps not as many. The Peano axioms are succinct, but Gödelization is complicated. On the other hand, LISP requires a decent amount of description at first, but the elegance of the language by essentially specifying an AST allows to write a LISP interpreter in a fairly short form. There seems to be some information theoretic trade-off. I am not interested in advanced language features like arithmetic, however, it just needs to be universal.

Comment: This is the question -- fundamental to the philosophy of natural science -- I came to this site to ask.

The reason it is fundamental to the philosophy of natural science is the same reason that Algorithmic Information is fundamental to the philosophy of natural science:

The algorithmic information of a dataset is the most principled model selection criterion for those observations.  This has profound implications for identification, measurement and discounting of "bias in the data" that plagues the is/ought confusion of "algorithmic bias" theory.